# Can we synonymize [restapi] to [rest]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

[rest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rest) has several synonyms already, including [rest-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rest-api). However, it seems there's another lookalike which has slipped our notice: [restapi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/restapi) (same as above, but without the `-`). The tag wiki for [restapi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/restapi) clearly indicates it is about the same thing:

> Use this tag for questions on how to build or use a REST API.

This seems pretty straightforward... can [restapi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/restapi) please be synonymized to [rest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rest)?

Comment: The tag wiki is a good start, but not really sufficient. Did you have a look through the questions with that tag, and make sure that they're all (> 90%) being used as [[tag:rest]]? I realize there are a *lot* of questions currently tagged [[tag:restapi]], but still fewer than after we merge into [[tag:rest]].

Comment: @CodyGray I'm not sure I follow. "restapi" is *more* specific than "rest", so it's *less* likely that someone will use [tag:restapi] to refer to something other than a REST API than it would be for someone to use [tag:rest] to mean something else... but that aside, to talk about REST is to talk about a REST API... there is no "REST <something other than an API".

Comment: @CodyGray Perhaps it would help convince you that [tag:restapi] only has records back to last year, and it has since led to at least one user misguidedly trying to move the site away from [tag:rest] single-handedly: https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/404470/4 as part of trying to remove [tag:api] uses (start here and move toward more recent edits: https://stackoverflow.com/users/9213345/henke?tab=activity&sort=suggestions&page=10)

Comment: Ah, I see... Gonna leave this up for a few more hours to see if someone screams "no"; otherwise, I'll pull the trigger.

Comment: Feel like this needs a funnier title: I propose "Should we lay `restapi` to `rest`"

Comment: I will note that the original concept of REST from Roy Fielding's paper that introduced the term is wildly unrelated to what people call "REST APIs". In a RESTful system (as described by Fielding), a user uses a generic client (e.g. a browser) to read and navigate hypermedia (e.g. HTML pages) and does not need external sources (e.g. documentation) to know how to use the system. This is nothing like what devs call a "REST API"; indeed an API is almost by definition not RESTful, and [Roy says "there is no such thing as a REST API"](https://mobile.twitter.com/fielding/status/1108177659375214592).

Comment: For some inscrutable reason, web devs appropriated Fielding's terminology to describe a common pattern for implementing web APIs in which URLs identify resources, nested resources are described by nested URLs, and standard HTTP methods describe actions to perform on those resources, with POST conventionally taken to mean "create" and the verbs GET, PUT, PATCH, and DELETE performing the actions described by the HTTP spec. It's a nice pattern. But it has not the slightest thing to do with what Fielding called "REST", and it's bizarre that this pattern somehow came to be known as a "REST API".

Comment: @MarkAmery Marketing is fun

Comment: Given the history of the terminology, there might've been some logic in avoiding creating any of these synonyms, and using the `rest` tag to describe Fielding's original concept and `rest-api` to describe the thing web devs re-appropriated Fielding's terminology to describe. But the horse has bolted now. And I'm probably kidding myself, anyway - the `rest` tag I envisage would of course be overwhelmed with questions about "REST APIs".

Comment: @MarkAmery I mean an API is just one form of client-server communication, which is what REST is all about.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I am all for it. I checked some of them and all of them are either about using REST API or building REST API. They don't refer to any particular subset of REST technology.

REST is used to build stateless APIs. Having two separate tags for REST serves no purpose. It's all the same IMHO.

The fact that [rest-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rest-api) is already a synonym makes it a clear case. The new [restapi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/restapi) tag should also be a synonym.

Comment: I just [did suggest](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms?tab=Newest&filter=Suggested) it

Comment: REST isn't technology.  It is a design principle for designing APIs.  Which makes me think that `[rest-api]` -> `[rest]` might have been a mistake.  Though questions about REST *per se* rather than RESTful APIs are probably off-topic.  Should be on SoftwareEngineering.

Comment: @StephenC What's problematic about that synonymization? "REST-API" is redundant compared to "REST" (at least as far as the purpose of tags goes) so I don't see an issue.

Comment: Ermm no.  They mean different things to me.  One is about the REST principles and how to apply them.  In other words API design.  The other is (usually) about *using* some API that has been design to be RESTful.  But maybe that distinction is too fine.

Comment: @StephenC I understand what you mean but the distinction is negligible. If you are asking about REST on Stack Overflow it's either about building API or using one.

Comment: Well it should be irrelevant because discussion of REST principles and the "correct" (aka "best practice") way to apply them should be off-topic.  But we all know that people ask questions in the wrong place, and other people answer them rather than calling them out as off-topic.   Anyhow. It is too late to undo that synonym.  And probably pointless.

Comment: @StephenC I see your point, but I agree that that distinction is too fine for the purposes of Stack Overflow. In terms of practical programming questions, there is no difference between *how to apply REST principles* (what would one be applying them to? An API (or one may choose to call it a "web service" instead of "API" if the client is not a person)) and *how to use a REST API*.

Comment: Perhaps you would prefer if we made [tag:restapi] a synonym of [tag:rest-api] instead, and then a separate discussion could be had about de-synonymizing [tag:rest-api] from [tag:rest]...

Comment: The point @StephenC is trying to convey is that [rest-api] shouldn't exist, but a [whatever-api] that happens to be restful

Comment: @Braiam I don't think so, because that wouldn't be particularly accurate regarding what REST *is*. "REST" is to "API" like "screw" is to "fastener". You cannot use a screw as a [wall stud](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wall_stud) instead, just like you cannot "use REST" for something other than an API. Anyway, [rest-api] *doesn't* exist, in effect... it's just [rest] currently.

Comment: @TylerH so, http is what to a user client called browser? Here we are talking about the differences between the implementation and the specification. The "REST principles and how to apply them" is the spec, vs "using some API that has been design to be RESTful" is an implementation. Neither is equivalent.

Comment: @Braiam http is the delivery method, like "screwdriver" or "impact driver"